# Extract the summary of data using groupby and optimize the inspector utilisation - pandas and and other optimisation package in python

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby, mathematical-optimization

I have accident record data as shown below across the places

```
    Inspector_ID    Place   Date
0   1               A   1-09-2019
1   2               A   1-09-2019
2   1               A   1-09-2019
3   1               B   1-09-2019
4   3               A   1-09-2019
5   3               A   1-09-2019
6   1               A   2-09-2019
7   3               A   2-09-2019
8   2               B   2-09-2019
9   3               A   3-09-2019
10  1               C   3-09-2019
11  1               D   3-09-2019
12  1               A   3-09-2019
13  1               E   3-09-2019
14  1               A   3-09-2019
15  1               A   3-09-2019
16  3               A   4-09-2019
17  3               B   5-09-2019
18  4               B   5-09-2019
19  3               A   5-09-2019
20  3               C   5-09-2019
21  3               A   5-09-2019
22  3               D   5-09-2019
23  3               C   5-09-2019
```

From the above data, I want to optimize the inspector utlisation.

for that tried below codes get the objective function of the optimisation.

```
c = df.groupby('Place').Inspector_ID.agg(
    Total_Number_of_accidents='count',
    Number_unique_Inspector='nunique',
    Unique_Inspector='unique').reset_index().sort_values(['Total_Number_of_accidents'], ascending=False)
```

Below is the output of above code

```
   Place    Total_Number_of_accidents   Number_unique_Inspector Unique_Inspector
0   A       14                          3                       [1, 2, 3]
1   B       4                           4                       [1, 2, 3, 4]
2   C       3                           2                       [1, 3]
3   D       2                           2                       [1, 3]
4   E       1                           1                       [1]
```

And then

```
f = df.groupby('Inspector_ID').Place.agg(
    Total_Number_of_accidents='count',
    Number_unique_Place='nunique',
    Unique_Place='unique').reset_index().sort_values(['Total_Number_of_accidents'], ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
    Inspector_ID    Total_Number_of_accidents   Number_unique_Place Unique_Place
2   3               11                          4                   [A, B, C, D]
0   1               10                          5                   [A, B, C, D, E]
1   2               2                           2                   [A, B]
3   4               1                           1                   [B]
```

From the above we have 4 Inspectors, 5 Places and 24 accidents. I want to optimize the allocation of inspectors based on the above data.

condition 1 - There should be at least 1 inspector in each Place.

condition 2 - All inspector should be assigned at least one Place.

Condition 3 - Identify the Place which is over utilised based on number of accidents (for eg: Place - B - Only 4 accidents and four inspector, So some inpspector from Place B can be assigned to Place A and next question is which inspector? and How many?.

Is it possible to do that in python, if possible which algorithm? and how?

Comment: you can always ask on https://or.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

it is an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem maybe it should be reduced to max-flow problem but with optimization of equality in flow (using graph package like NetworkX):

how to create di-graph:

vertice ***s*** source of flow (of accidents)
***S***-*set* would be all places that will have accidents
***X_s*** - set of all edges  (***s***, ***x***) where ***x*** in ***S***, now ***t*** is sink, and we have analogus sets ***T*** and ***X_t*** now let's set capacity for edges in ***X_s*** - it would be set from column `Total_Number_of_accidents` in ***X_t*** we would set max number of accidents to process by inspector and we will get back to it later on, now let's make edges from ***S*** to ***T*** (***x***, ***y***) where ***x*** in ***X_s*** and ***y*** in ***X_t*** and let's set capacity of these edges to high number (e.g. 1e6) and let's call this set ***X_c*** these edges will tell us how much load will get inspector ***y*** from place ***x***.

now solve max-flow problem, and when some edges from ***X_t*** would have too big flow you can decrease capacity of these (to reduce load on particular inspector) and when some edges in ***X_c*** will have very small flow you can just remove these edges to reduce complexity of work organization, after few iterations you should have desired solution

you can code some super algorithm but if it's real life problem you would like to avoid situations like assigning one inspector to all places and to process 0.38234 accident at each place...

- also there should be probably some constraints on how many accidents should be processed by inspector in given time but you didn't mentioned it...